# CCS PICC CCP settings

Tags: c, microcontroller, benchmarking

*(I'll gladly post code if someone can point out how to paste it in here without using the 4 space indentation system that doesn't work)*

Hello folks
After ~9Hours racking by brains, I can't find an answer or find where my calculations are going wrong... but they are.
I have a circuit built using a microchip 18F2550 microcontroller.
I am using this circuit to measure the delay between 2 signals and am using the 2 CCP registers in capture mode.
This all works and the result is sent to the PC (over USB serial) all dandy, but the results are wrong.
I have to apply a gain of ~16000 to any results to get somewhere near the delay presented to the pins.

I have the delay set in the line
Timer1 is set as an internal
Timer3 is disabled
relevant interrupts are enabled

and the main routine runs continuously.
When I get a rising edge detection on the CCP1 pin, the interrupt is configured to reset timer1 to zero as well as the overflow counter

```
    #INT_CCP1
    void ccp1_isr() // Captures the rising edge of CCP1 pin.
    { 
        if(timing==FALSE){ // only do this on the edge, any bouncing will reset timers etc.
            set_timer1(0);
            T1_Overflow = 0;
            Pulse_Time = 0;
            timing = 1;     // Set flag to indicate timing.
            output_high(BLUE_LED);
        }
    }
```

the `timing` flag ensures the times cannot be reset by another pulse on the CCP1 pin.
Timer1 should then be reset and start counting as normal.  Every time it rolls around by 65535 (16bit device) another interrupt is fired after which the amount of overflows are incremented.

```
    #INT_TIMER1
    void isr()
    {
        T1_Overflow++;
    }
```

Finally, when the input pin on CCP2 goes high, the CCP_2 interrupt is triggered.  This captures the value of the CCP register (which is the value of Timer0 at the time the interrupt was fired) and the overflow register.

```
    #INT_CCP2
    void ccp2_isr()                 
    {   
        if(timing == TRUE){ // only output this when preceded by CCP1
            if(Count_Done == FALSE) // do this once only
            {
                Count_Done = TRUE;  // and also flag to the main routine to output data to the terminal.
                Pulse_time = CCP_2;
                Pulse_Overflow = T1_Overflow;
                measureCount++;     // increment the number of measures.
            }
            output_low(BLUE_LED);
            timing = FALSE;
        }
    }
```

CCP1 can now start responding to the inputs again.
The idea of this is that every time I get a pulse of one input at CCP1 followed by CCP2, a string is sent to the terminal with a counter, the number of overflows and the time left in the timer.

```
    while(TRUE)                        // do forever while connected
    {       
       usb_task();                          // keep usb alive    
       if(Count_Done == TRUE)
       {
           printf(usb_cdc_putc, "%lu , %lu ,  %lu \r\n",measureCount, pulse_time, pulse_overflow);
           Count_Done = FALSE;
       }
```

so, I should get an output to the terminal of something like "1,61553,35" for a ~12ms delay between CCP1 and CCP2.
The problem is that these are the results I am getting for a 200ms pulse provided to the circuit. (Verified twice)

so where am I going wrong.
I have a 48MHZ Clock with no prescaler which implies a cycle every 20ns.
Divide by for 4 instructions per cycle for the clock which implies 5.2ns every cycle
16 bit timer which implies rollover every 65535*5.2ns = 341us per rollover.
when you do the calculations (0.000341*pulse_overflow)+pulse_time*(5.2*(10^-9))
then the above data gives 0012.27ms and not the 200ms provided.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong with these calculations???

Comment: The code fails, during any interrupt, to clear the associated interrupt flag.  This means the next interrupt for that interrupt source will occur immediately after returning from the interrupt.

Comment: the ccp1_isr() interrupt function needs to initialize the timer1 registers and start the timer1 counting.  Per the documentation, the timer1 counter counts 1 time for each 'source' clock cycle so the count rate would be 1/48000000 second, not every 5.2nsec

Comment: the ccp2_isr() interrupt function needs to stop the timer1 from counting, otherwise it will keep counting and (upon overflow) increment the T1_Overflow variable.

Comment: The manual for the pick chip is at: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf  It contains example code.  It would be well worth your while to read/understand it.

Comment: See below.  It mostly works but is off by only ~2ms, although what I am trying to measure is at the us range so this might not work.  I want the system to keep counting as I don't want a start/stop to interfere with the timing.  When the primary input is detected the timer is set to zero along with the overflow count.  These are copied out in the second interrupt (CCP2) which should provide accurate timing.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in "Divide by for 4 instructions per cycle for the clock which implies 5.2ns every cycle"

The counter ticks once every 4 cycles, not 4 times per cycle. So, the correct calculations are:

2.08333E-08 s/cycle of osc

8.33333E-08 s/tick of timer

0.005461333 s/rollover

You are off by a factor of 16.

Comment: I had just spotted this, thank you (seriously, I did!!!) I would thank uou and vote up but I don't have enough reputation. I am having one more issue you may be able to help me with though.

Comment: once I have populated the calculations above with the correct offsets :-|  I am still not getting the correct results from the calculation.  I have my circuit connected to a PLC generating a 200ms pulse between setting 2 outputs but my circuit seems to be reading ~198ms average with only 9% of readings over the 200ms.  I expected some inaccuracies due to PLC IO update rates and scan cycle updates mapped to the I/O but this should make the readings greater than 200ms, not less than.  I've gone over the calculations again and I cannot see where the innacuracies are coming from.

Comment: Here are a couple ways to debug this. 1. Change the PLC code to make a 400 ms pulse; do you get ~398 or ~396 on the PIC? ~398 implies an offset error, ~396 implies a gain error. 2. Put an oscilloscope on the signal and see how long the pulse really is!

Comment: Hi Doug.  I've altered the PLC for both 100ms, 200ms and 350ms with the following results...<br/> 200: 0.198382397,
100: 0.098396719,
350: 0.348611943,
50: 0.048654478.  As can be seen there is no real correlation between the reductions.  I am thinking that this could be an issue with the temperature of the chip as I am using a USB serial interface leading to T1 operating of the internal RC oscillator so I'll have a go at offsetting OSCTUNE based on the results from a scope.

Comment: After some digging as to where the 4ms was going missing, I took some reccommendations from a friend to reprogram the timer.  I am using a Siemens S7 and had the S_PEXT timer function managing the time.  I changed this to a cyclic interrupt ever 10ms and a counter to provide the timing.  My values are now coming in at 200ms on the nose.  Thanks Doug for your help. If I had the reputation, I'd +1.